# Сжатие фото на сайте wordpress

Tags: wordpress, сжатие

Проблема возникла ожидаемо. Заканчивается место на хостинге для хранения данных. Есть ли методы сжатия файлов без их потери качества?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для всех своих проектов используем [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/) - он напрямую обращается к серверным утилитам для компрессии, умеет сжимать произвольные папки, пережимать старые фотки, работать по крону, задавать уровни компрессий по типам файлов, исключать размеры из сжатия - и еще много чего умеет. Если не хочется напрягать сервер, можно использовать внешние ресурсы типа: [Imagify](https://imagify.io/) или [WP Smush](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wp-smush-pro) - оба имеют плагины под WordPress.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Тоже хорошо. Учту.

Answer (score 0):

Не так давно у меня возникал подобный вопрос. После долгих исследований мой выбор пал на плагин [Compress JPEG & PNG images](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/tiny-compress-images/). Он бесплатный, не создает нагрузок на сервер и сжимает изображения лучше других плагинов.

При этом, сжатие происходит без потери качества - удаляются ненужные exif-данные. Единственный недостаток - это лимит на сжатие - "всего" 500 изображений.

Comment: Спасибо за предложенный вариант. Попробую обязательно.